# Using Ejabberd as App Server in XMPP push notification service

Tags: push-notification, architecture, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I am making a chat app which is using ejabberd as primary server and not using any seperate App server for Authentication and all. I want to implement push notification as described in [XEP-0357: Push Notifications] (https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0357.html) .

While implementing it i came to know that we have to use app server and that app server in returns should be able to create a PubSub Node in XMPP Push Service.

Is there any way so i can use Ejabberd as App server and use XMPP push service in it combinely. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You often will need to develope your own App Server, because it must fit your usecase. But for example you could look at the code of the Conversations app server and get some inspiration from there: https://github.com/iNPUTmice/p2

This app server acts as an component (https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0114.html) which would I recommend to also do because then you can just hand it into your ejabberd.